# Django template/form for user input

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I have a basic django-rest API running for a program I wrote. The program retrieves data from a database and displays it on the browser. The database is queried using two input values 'a' and 'b'.

Ex:

```
a = raw_input('Enter A.')
b = raw_input('Enter B.')
response = HttpResponse()
for post in db.collection.find({'field1' : a, 'field2' : b})
    response.write(post)
return response
```

Instead of the raw_input statements, how do I write a code that will enable the user to enter the values for 'a' and 'b' from the browser?

When I enter the URL, I should have a page to input 'a' and 'b'. Once I hit Submit, it should display the posts (done by return response ). There is no 'PUT' function, only 'GET' using the user inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you need a page with a form on it first of all;

```
<form action="{% url 'searchview' %}" method="GET">
  <label>A:</label>
    <input name="a">
  <label>B:</label>  
    <input name="b">

    <button type="submit">
        Search
    </button>
</form>
```

Then an URL to capture that;

```
url(r'^search/(?P<a>\w+)/(?P<b>\w+)/$', 'views.search_view', name="searchview")
```

Then a view to handle that URL;

```
def search_view(request, a, b):
    myobj = MyModel.objects.get(field1=a, field2=b)
```

Or a class based view would be something like;

```
class SearchView(View):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        a = request.GET['a']
        b = request.GET['b']
        obj = self.model.get(field1=a, field2=b)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'obj': obj})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're submitting the form using GET, then the values should be in `request.GET`. So something like `request.GET['a']`? The `request` object should be available in your Django view.